# Display the Output of ADB Command in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, adb

I am working on a project to display the CPU Usage in Android and I came across adb command that will display the same.

```
adb shell top -m 10
```

I have a requirement to display this output as a Button Click event in Android Studio. When I click the Button, then the CPU usage outputs can be rendered in a new window or so.

How do I exactly parse this command in the Android Studio ?

I am basically new to Android programming and I am waiting for your valuable inputs on this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So are you trying to do something within the app itself, or within the IDE?

Comment: Within the app itself followed by some button click perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this code on button click listener may be works;

private float readUsage() {

try {

```
RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/stat", "r");

String load = reader.readLine();

String[] toks = load.split(" ");

long idle1 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);
```

long cpu1 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) +    Long.parseLong(toks[4])
          + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

try {

```
  Thread.sleep(360);
} 
catch (Exception e) {}

reader.seek(0);

load = reader.readLine();

reader.close();

toks = load.split(" ");

long idle2 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);

long cpu2 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[4])
    + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);
```

return (float)(cpu2 - cpu1) / ((cpu2 + idle2) - (cpu1 + idle1));
}

catch (IOException ex) {

```
   ex.printStackTrace();
```

}

return 0;

}